# MyApp.getInitialProps return pageProps as empty object

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
/pages/_app.jsx
import App from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  console.log(pageProps)  // --> Empty object
  return (
    <Provider>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </Provider>
  );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext)
  return { ...appProps }
}
```

I want to get all generated pages. The app generates about 1000 pages, but pageProps is an empty object.
I am looking for a solution to get all generated pages with NextJS

Comment: `MyApp.getInitialProps` is just passing what it gets from the page's `getInitialProps`, so that's not the issue. Can you show us what the `getInitialProps` in one of your pages looks like?

Answer (score 0):

1. `getInitialProps` is `async`.
2. U have some problems with data you returning from `getInitialProps`, here is an example

   ```
   MyApp.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
     //your API route or function using api
     const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext)
     //you need to await data 
     const res= await appProps.json()
     // in your MyApp you use 'data' variable
     return { data: res }
   }
   ```
3. From nextjs v9+ it's recommended to use [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps)

Comment: On your second point `await appProps.json()` - that's not right, the `appProps` returned by `App.getInitialProps` is already a JSON object. OP's code in `MyApp.getInitialProps` is fine.

Comment: So then just `return` modification to `return {data: appProps}`

Comment: You actually want to pass through the props you get from the page's `getInitialProps`, doing what you're suggesting will make them all be inside the `data` object, which is not what you'd want here. `return { ...appProps }` is correct in this case. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app.